# Won't print a combination of int and str

Tags: python, prettytable

Dumb script to calculate the savings when buying bulk medical flower.

Tried wrapping it in str() to see if that converted it all into a string so it could print().

```py
from prettytable import PrettyTable
    print("*Enter with spaces seperating")
    oneGP, twoGP, OneEightP, OneFourP, OneHalfP, ozP= map(int, input().split(" "))

    x = PrettyTable()

    x.field_names = ["1g", "2g", "1/8", "1/4", "1/2" "Oz"]

    x.add_row(["$" + oneGP, "$" + twoGP, "$" + OneEightP, "$" + OneFourP,"$" + OneHalfP, "$" + ozP])
    x.add_row([oneGP/1, twoGP/2, OneEightP/3.5, OneFourP/7,OneHalfP/14,ozP/28])

    print(x)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 10, in
>   
>       x.add_row(["$" + oneGP, "$" + twoGP, "$" + OneEightP, "$" + OneFourP,"$" + OneHalfP, "$" + ozP]) TypeError: can only concatenate
>   str (not "int") to str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x.add_row(["$" + str(oneGP), "$" + str(twoGP), "$" + str(OneEightP), "$" + str(OneFourP),"$" + str(OneHalfP), "$" + str(ozP)])
```

you tried to concat int to string so this error happens + will work with same type objects so you need to use cast for some cases
or if you don't want to cast use `,` instead of `+`